# How will I save data from javascript's canvas.toDataURL to an image file in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, save-image

How will I save data from javascript's canvas.toDataURL to an image file in ruby?

The sample code below create the image but gives an error saying the format is not recognized or damaged

```
require 'base64'
chart1 = params[:chart1].split(',')
image = Base64.decode64(chart1[1])

File.open("#{Rails.root}/test.png", 'wb') do|f|
  f.write(image)
end
```

Thanks!

**NOTE: Edited. This is now ok and working**

Comment: What value is in `chart1[1]`? Have you tried using a debugger to step through your code?

Comment: why do you have to call Base64.decode64 twice?

Comment: @p0rter nice catch. its now working. tnx

Comment: @p0rter - If you're game to recap the solution as your own answer, I'll delete my answer. (See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90263/unanswered-question-answered-in-comments for elaboration of why this is helpful.) Thanks!

Comment: @steamboy hey dude.plz help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21980880/sending-input-type-image-to-a-folder-on-the-server/21981131?noredirect=1#comment33310449_21981131 
its same as your question

Answer (score 0):

Copying the answer from the comments in order to remove this question from the "Unanswered" filter:

[p0rter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1228509/p0rter) noticed:

> why do you have to call Base64.decode64 twice?

[steamboy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/282360/steamboy) acknowledged:

> @p0rter nice catch. its now working. tnx