# Sending <input type="image"> to a folder on the server

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms

I have this code

```
<%= form_for(:img, url: {action: "postodb"}) do |f| %>
<div id="image-preview">image here!</div>
<%= f.submit "Send to database" %>
<%end%>
```

Here `<input type="image">` is added from a js file

```
var imageDiv = $("#image-preview");
  imageDiv.html('<input type="image" name="img1" style="margin-left:146px"id="spiro-img" src="'+img+'"/>');
```

This all works fine..

Next I want to send this to the folder but it doesnt work

This is the code I have in the controller(referred from this site http://rohitrox.github.io/2013/07/19/canvas-images-and-rails/)

```
def postodb
data = params[:data_uri]
image_data = Base64.decode64(data['data:image/png;base64,'.length .. -1])

File.open("/public/uploads/somefilename.png", 'wb') do |f|
  f.write image_data
end
end
```

This is the error I get

[image]

Plz help.

Answer (score 1):

Using [carrierwave gem](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) for loading images.

Comment: will i able to store the images in the folders?

Comment: Yes. It's very flexible, you may upload images in folder, db, amazon s3 and etc.

Comment: but the thing is i m not using <input type="file">,but i m using<input type="image"> will it work?coz i tried searching on google but couldnt find nything relevant

Comment: I don't try `type="image"`, but you may use `type="file"` and add to upload-controller method with needed extensions:
`def extension_white_list
  %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
end`

Comment: with type file i know how to do it.In my case i create an image using css on a canvas and then store it in the file image tag.So i need to pass this image to the folder but it doesnt work

Comment: do i need to add something in the models?also where do i put the require base64 statement?

Answer (score 1):

First what your should to do is read a docs: http://www.w3schools.com/Tags/att_input_type.asp

> **image** - Defines an image as the submit button.

Second what your should learn to read is logs. At screenshot you have section with params, and there is no `data_uri` key.

And finaly use the `<input type='file' ... />` for upload. If you want beauty async upload with preview, you should look on `jquery-file-upload` gem instead.

P.S.: `type='image'` is a submit button with image.

Comment: but in this link they have shown  http://rohitrox.github.io/2013/07/19/canvas-images-and-rails/

Comment: This bad idea. You should use element for which it is designed for.

Comment: i have no choice,you could suggest me something...this is my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/26Ws4/7/ ...here i create the image,and this image i need to send to the server folder..